# Calling on a VBA procedure that generates a chart using ARRAY data

Tags: arrays, vba, charts

So, I have created an array, and I am trying to put the data into a chart... but I have no clue how to make the chart take on the data from an array I generated, rather than from a range. I coded for a chart uding a Range from an excel sheet.. but I can't see how to make all of that happen when I have this array..

I have two sub procedures. Inside one of them I want to use

```
Call ChartNew2(myArray)
```

How can I do that? I tried in this way and I wasn't successful either...

```
Sub ChartNew2(result2 As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
ReDim result2(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
Charts.Add
    For i = LBound(result2, 1) To UBound(result2, 1)
        result2(i, 1) = result2
    Next i
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject

    With ActiveChart
                .HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        End With


    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
                .HasMajorGridlines = True
    End With

    ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)

            .MaximumScale = 1

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It generates a blank page..

Comment: Is it acceptable to drop your array values on a page, create a range against it and get the chart to build from the range?

Comment: I wouldn't like to do it, unless I can do it and then let the values in those ranges disappear, cause they would look VERY ugly.

Comment: You can probably hide the worksheet with the values on it. Then you wouldn't have to behold its ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

This link: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/400227-making-charts-from-arrays-in-vba.html

says to use this syntax:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = MyXArray
    .Values = MyYArray
    .Name = MyName
End With
```

If you're having troubles passing arrays, I think this is the syntax if your array is an integer array.

```
Sub ChartNew2(result2() As Integer)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it but the problem is the  array values are generated by a different Sub procedure... And then I call on them. I don't know how to refer correctly to that array...

Comment: So you've validated that that code works if the arrays are local? S the real problem is passing arrays, not using them in charts?

Comment: I actually have my array as a Variant, and it works as a Variant.. Integer wouldn't cause I don't have integers.

Comment: How do you chart a variant? Surely they are numbers of some kind. Anyway, does it work if you use Variant instead of Integer?

Comment: Oh now that I do some reading it seems you know more than me :). When you use your code as-is, what line does the error occur on?

Comment: It's curious that your array appears to be 4x1 - is that right? Can you give us a clue as to it's dimensions before it is passed in?

Comment: Yes, 4 by 1. The error is when I do Call ChartNew2(result2) ! Something is an invalid parameter

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm about to tackle a v.similar problem so any jump start would be good!

Comment: Hi @ammarorama, it's best to just give it a go and post any specific errors in a new question.